# Stuck on developing a combat function

Tags: python

basically im learning to code and saw this nice dragon realm example task. Everything was fine until i reached the stage where i want to engage in combat.

```
    def cave_2_fight():
        def monster_hit():
            m_hit = random.randint(1, 11)
            return m_hit

        def player_hit():
            p_hit = random.randint(1, 11)
            return p_hit

        monster_hp = random.randint(1, 101)
        player_hp = 100
        print("You are being attacked by a goblin with {} hp".format(monster_hp))
        print("Getting ready text")
        while monster_hp != 0 or player_hp != 0:
            attack_area = input("Where do you want to hit him[top or mid or bot]: ")
            if attack_area == 'top':
                p_dmg = player_hit()
                m_dmg = monster_hit()
                print('You hit goblin for {} and he hits you for {}'.format(p_dmg, m_dmg))
                player_hp = player_hp - m_dmg
                monster_hp = monster_hp - p_dmg
                return player_hp, monster_hp

            elif attack_area == "mid":
                p_dmg = player_hit()
                m_dmg = monster_hit()
                print('You hit goblin for {} and he hits you for {}'.format(p_dmg, m_dmg))
                player_hp = player_hp - m_dmg
                monster_hp = monster_hp - p_dmg
```

I want it to be random a bit, and im really stuck in returning to choosing attack_area after i negaged for the first time. Thanks in advance

Comment: im getting minused so hard , why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                return player_hp, monster_hp
```

exits the function. You should take out this line - monster_hp and player_hp will get updated without it.

Also, you should probably change

```
    while monster_hp != 0 or player_hp != 0:
```

to

```
    while monster_hp > 0 or player_hp > 0:
```

since it's possible that someone's hp will go negative. If you want the game to end whenever either player dies, change the "or" to "and" (this will require them both to be alive.)

You're probably getting downvoted because a) it's not at all clear what your problem with your code is (I guessed), and b) the code you posted isn't an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): the first line will give a syntax error (I think this is just an indentation problem with the copy-pasting.)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply, i will try to be more exact in the future with my questions. Fixed my copy paster error and your solution worked perfectly. Thanks alot m8 !